# A strange (because i am new in python) result when i update self variable. Why this happens?

Tags: python, loops, class, self

It is now one week that i am stuck with this and i don't know why it is happening. So i want to present to you my problem to see if you have a solution.

I have this code. My purpose here is to update this variables A and B using a loop. So, i first execute all calcs using A and B that i give when i call the class, then the code compute gamma and xi and finally i want to compute new A and B.

I create in my class first the functions that i use to find the values that i need to use for computing gamma and xi. Then i create functions that i use to find gamma and xi. In this function i call the previous functions with self.fun.

Then i create the function that i show here to compute new A and B values and i insert this in a loop because i want to iterate this function until i reach a convergence.

But...
This method works correctly to compute A, but, when it needs to compute B, it uses the new A before computing B. It implies that, when it computes A, old A and B are used to compute gamma and xi and then A. Where it computes B, it uses new A and B to compute gamma and xi but i want that it uses the same that it uses to compute first A.

```
      def update(self):
        for n in range(self.iter):
            gamma = self.gamma()
            xi = self.xi()
            # new trans matrix
            new_A = []
            for i in range(len(self.A)):
                temp = []
                for j in range(len(self.A[i])):
                    numerator = 0
                    denominator = 0
                    for r in range(len(self.seq)):
                        for t in range(len(xi[r])):
                            numerator += xi[r][t][i][j]
                            denominator += gamma[r][t][i]

                    aij = numerator / denominator
                    temp.append(aij)
                new_A.append(temp)

            self.A = new_A
            emission_signals = unique(self.seq[0])
            emission_matrix = []

            for k in range(len(emission_signals)):
                emission_matrix.append([])
                for i in range(len(self.A)):
                    gamma_vec = []
                    gamma_num = []
                    for r in range(len(self.seq)):
                        for t in range(len(self.seq[r])):
                            gamma_append = gamma[r][t][i]
                            gamma_vec.append(gamma_append)
                            if self.seq[r][t] == emission_signals[k]:
                                gamma_num_append = gamma[r][t][i]
                                gamma_num.append(gamma_num_append)
                        bik = sum(gamma_num) / sum(gamma_vec)
                        emission_matrix[k].append(bik)

            new_B = {}
            keys = emission_signals
            for i in range(len(keys)):
                new_B[keys[i]] = emission_matrix[i]
            self.A = new_A
            self.B = new_B


        return {'A': self.A, 'B': self.B}
```

I don't know if i'm explaining well but this is my problem.
Hope that you can help me!

Thank you !

Comment: You did `self.A = new_A` before calculating `new_B`.

Comment: You did this once in the middle of the function, and then redundantly at the end. It sounds like the first one is a mistake.

Comment: you're right. I cut off this but the problem remains.

Comment: If i use new_A and new_B in return, it gives me the correct solution, but if i inser self.A = new_A and self.B = new_B, things go wrong

Comment: you never even use the contents of `self.A` or `self.B`, except for using their lengths as the limits of your `for` loops.

Comment: they are used in gamma and xi function at the top of this function

Comment: Since those are called before you reassign `self.A` and `self.B`, they can't possibly use the new values.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without seeing the rest of your code, but it looks like you are referencing mutable objects A and B (list and dict) multiple times, and editing them from different places.

Just take into account, in python, every time you assign a mutable object to a variable, you are only creating a new reference to same object and not copying it. So every edit you do on that object, will be reflected on all its references.

Comment: i found the problem. if i use print(self.update())   i obtain the right values, but if i use '' print(self.update().get('A'))
        print(self.update().get('B'))'' i have the mistake.    i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the problem was this:

```
 print(self.update().get('A'))
        print(self.update().get('B'))
```

I change it in this way and now it works but i do not understand the logic behind this.

```
     a = self.update()
     print('\n---New transition matrix... ---')
     print(a.get('A'))
     print('\n---New Emission matrix... ---')
     print(a.get('B'))
```

Maybe in the previous way i call update 2 times and then calculations go wrong. i don't know.